# firefox downloading something hiddenly

Tags: windows, firefox, resources

I just detected high data usage by Firefox even when no  web page is opened.it's really a problem because all my data consume by Firefox quickly . this is a snap shot

[image]

My question is can i identify what's downloading and how can i stop it. 
i don't  have installed any add-on.currently i can see data is consume by Firefox using resources monitor but i want to know what is downloading

Comment: It looks like you are talking about 95KB of data, which is rather miniscule, and thus will be hard to track. it could be update checking, bookmark synch checking, cert recovation checking, speculative warmup as Romeo mentions, or a large number of other items. you could attempt to view the connections in TCPView, and determine to whom they are made, and you could attempt to capture the packets, but in the long run, this will be difficult, and probably unproductive if all we are talking about is an odd 100KB.

Comment: @franks 95KB ?but problem is it's always downloading at about  400kbps-1.8mbps.if it's bookmark checking it should be download at about 10sec 1min...but it keep downloading .and when i goto a address it take lot time to load cuz hidden downloading

Comment: If that is the case, then your image isn't showing what you want us to see. at 400kbps, it would take less than 2 seconds to pull the data your image shows. remember the meter there is showing you totals for the box, not just for the firefox process. in fact, it looks like the total network IO for the process is 4kbps, which most would consider trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have firefox 38 you may want to check [release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/38.0/releasenotes/) for the version where you will find this:

> Improved page load times via speculative connection warmup

You can disable it by switching the preference `network.predictor.enabled` to false.

Comment: Not sure if this would already run when not even loading any page? (And it seems the previous version only established connections, but did not load any data?) But that's easily tested by disabling it.

Comment: it was true and i changed to false .is this cause to consume data

Comment: Are you saying this fixed it for you, @FastSnail? (Then please "accept" this as the helpful answer.)

Comment: it seems yes.but will check more and accept